# react-native Splash Screen as a component (Android&Ios)

Tags: android, ios, animation, react-native, splash-screen

I made a component for SplashScreen since I wanted to use animations in it. However, I couldn't find the way how to insert this component as a splash screen. Any advise?

Comment: what kind of animation you want to show in splash screen?

Comment: On iOS this will just need to be the initial viewcontroller you load; the actual splash screen that is displayed by iOS cannot have any code behind it since it is shown before any code runs.

Comment: Ok, i changed it as an image. Thank you Paul.